# Clicking and removing an item in a for loop also affect another item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17

Clicking on the second button in a @for-list changes the state to `true` of the 2nd and 3rd buttons when using it as a component. When using the button from the component directly, it works correctly: the state of the 2nd button is `true`, while the state of the 3rd button is still `false`. Why is that?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-akdlrv?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    Clicking on second button changes state of 2nd and 3rd button when using as component<br><br>
    When using the button component directly, it works correctly<br><br>
    undone:
    @for (todo of undoneTodos; track $index) {
      <!-- <button (click)="toggle(todo)">{{ todo.done }}</button> -->
      <app-slider [id]="'undone-'+$index" [active]="todo.done" (activeChange)="toggle(todo)"></app-slider>
    }

    done:
    @for (todo of doneTodos; track $index) {
      <app-slider [id]="'done-'+$index" [active]="todo.done" (activeChange)="toggle(todo)"></app-slider>
    }
  `,
  imports: [SliderComponent]
})
export class App {
  undoneTodos: Todo[] = [];
  doneTodos: Todo[] = [];

  private todos: Todo[] = [
    {id: 1, done: false },
    {id: 2, done: false },
    {id: 3, done: false },
  ]

  constructor() {
    this.buildTodos();
  }

  toggle(todo: Todo) {
    todo.done = !todo.done

    this.buildTodos();
  }

  private buildTodos() {
    this.doneTodos = this.todos.filter(x => x.done);
    this.undoneTodos = this.todos.filter(x => !x.done);
  }
}

export interface Todo {
  id?: number;
  done: boolean;
}
```

slider.component.ts:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  standalone: true,
  template: '<button (click)="onClick($event)">{{ active }}</button>',
})
export class SliderComponent {
  @Input() active: boolean = false;
  @Output() activeChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  
  onClick(event: Event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    
    this.active = !this.active;
    this.activeChange.emit(this.active);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `track todo.id` instead of `track $index`.

```
@for (todo of undoneTodos; track todo.id) {
  <!-- <button (click)="toggle(todo)">{{todo.id}}: {{ todo.done }}</button> -->
  {{todo.id}}: <app-slider [id]="'undone-'+todo.id" [active]="todo.done" (activeChange)="toggle(todo)"></app-slider>
}

done:
@for (todo of doneTodos; track todo.id) {
  {{todo.id}}: <app-slider [id]="'done-'+todo.id" [active]="todo.done" (activeChange)="toggle(todo)"></app-slider>
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-h5jvgj?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

For your reading, [`track` for calculating difference of two collections](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow#track-for-calculating-difference-of-two-collectionsa):

> For collections that do not undergo modifications (no items are moved, added, or deleted), using `track $index` is an efficient strategy. For collections with mutable data or frequent changes, select a property that uniquely identifies each item to use as your track expression.